# jQuery click(), live() and on()

Tags: jquery

Just interested to know which of - `click()`, `live()` and `on()` is currently the preferred method to catch a user mouse click?

I assume `live()` is out as this I believe scans to much of the DOM.

Thank you.

Comment: TL;DR: `live` is deprecated, terrible and removed from 1.9, `bind` and `delegate` are outdated, `on` is the preferred way to bind arbitrary events and `click` is just fine, but kinda limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From jquery docs:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live(). This method provides a means to
>   attach delegated event handlers to the document element of a page,
>   which simplifies the use of event handlers when content is dynamically
>   added to a page. See the discussion of direct versus delegated events
>   in the .on() method for more information.
>
> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method
>   provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.

```
For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.
```

TLDR: Always use `on()` , never use `live()`

Answer (score 3):

`live()` and `.bind()` methods are deprecated. `live()` has also been removed where as other two are two totally two different types of event handlers.

1. `.click()` is a standard event handler

   ```
   .click(function() {
       //Applies to DOM already present
   });
   ```
2. `.on()` is used when you require *event delegation*. This replaced traditional `bind()` and `delegate()`

   ```
   .on('click', function() {
           //Delegates to each element is DOM as it manipulated or generated
   });
   ```

Comment: [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is not deprecated, merely superseeded.

Answer (score 2):

but jQuery 1.9 not supporting live function ,instead of you should use "on"

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: `live` is deprecated, `bind` and `delegate` are superseeded, `on` is the preferred way to bind arbitrary events and `click` is just fine, but kinda limited.

[`$(selector).live("click", ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated since 1.7, removed from jQuery since 1.9, inflexible (it always binds to `document`), extremely inefficient (it first finds the elements, then discards the selection and uses the selector instead), requires the selector to be stored in the jquery object and is generally bad.

[`$(document).on("click", selector, ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is the literal replacement for `live`, but it shares none of its misfeatures. It's the do-everything event binding function of jQuery. It can bind anything anywhere, or delegate to anything: `$parent.on(events, [targetSelector,]  handler)`. You can even bind multiple events at once: `.on("keypress paste change", ...)`

[`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) are older cousins of `on`. The former cannot delegate, the latter has to. They also differ in the argument order - `on` is here to settle that. They have been superseeded by `on`, but they have not been deprecated (as of jQuery 1.10). If you have to use an old version of jQuery (pre-1.7), there they are. Otherwise, stick to `on`. Their current implementation merely redirects to `on`.

`click`, `mouseOver`, `change` and [many other](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) serve as double-duty aliases for `on` and `trigger`. Literally - they do nothing else than to branch off to one of those. Most of them exist since the dawn of time and they are conveniently conscise. They can't delegate, however, and there are no corresponding unbinding methods for them. If you use `off`, it looks better to complement it with `on`. One nice property is that they bear with them a promise of cross-browser compatibility. Or at least a place where to document any lack of cross-browser support (namely: `load` for images). My personal preference is to use `on` even in cases where `click` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

"On" is the preferred method, because in future you can easily change it to another like "mouseup", "mousedown".